# Create a Wordpress plugin that finds text in a post/page and replaces it with links

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wiki

wordpress , plugins : hi , I want to create website by wordpress but I want to make speacial plugins .. and I made it but there are problem .. *_*

I have a website and I using it with wiki for contries in the world ..

I want from the plugins 'when the visitor open the page for example 'United State' , I want from the plugins to search about all of world in this page like cities ' New York , .... ' and replace it by like for city's page for example = New York  ..

I don't know how make it ..

I tried few times but I fail >_< ..

```
 <?php 
/*
Plugin Name: ReplaceMent

*/
$wiki_contry = array ("Japan"=>"<a href='?japan.php'> Japan <a/>","United State"=>"<a href='?usa.php'> United State <a/>");
function replace($text){
    foreach ($wiki_contry as $ky => $vl){
    $text = str_replace(ِ"$ky","$vl", $text);
    return $text;
    }
}
add_filter('the_content','replace');

?>
```

other world , I want my site like wikipidia but using wordpress and plugins ^_^..

thank you very much

Comment: O.o I don't even.. wha.. http://www.google.com/images?q=dude%20wait%20what%20cat

Comment: Poorly worded question, topic title should be more question-focused, and less on the topic at hand, that's why there are tags.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be frank but your English is terrible. I can't clearly understand what you're doing or why you're trying to do it.

Why would you want your site to be like Wikipedia utilizing Wordpress and its plugins when you can just use [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for free?

Comment: seanny94 , I know my English is terrible but what I can do? this is my ability .. ok .. 
I do not want to be like my wikipidia exactly .. I just want to make plugins to search in article if there word same another article ; for examle ; I wrote article about: Asia , okey 
in this article words like ' Japan , Korea , India , Saudi Arabia ' also , there are article about 'Japan , ... etc' , I want from this plugin to like the words to these articles .. I know my langauge very bad .. I wish you understood *_^

Comment: give the man a break!... instead of focusing on the quality of his English, why not try and help him reword it so that we can understand it. 

i think he's trying to do a plugin that searches a page content for keywords and transforms those keywords into links.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to quite an old post,
but .. the answer seems to be kind of missing,
so I am giving it a shot, to provide an answer.

Perhaps adding this in your function-body will help ?

```
global $wiki_contry;
```

And perhaps a less intense way to do it would be something along the lines of the content described in this article https://themefuse.com/wordpress-tutorial-how-to-link-keywords-to-urls-automatically/ . So, essentially a function that replaces the text content when it is saved, using WordPress-hook 'content_save_pre', to execute the replace function and save that text to the database.

```
add_filter('content_save_pre','replace_keywords_fn');
```

I would also like to suggest to you the idea of using tags for the countries and regions, so you can point to the overview page for that tag.